# Gii in Yii 1.1 not working in Mac showing error "Error 500 Only the first byte will be assigned to the string offset"

Tags: php, yii, gii

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDUe2.png)while adding more than one table in the database the Gii is showing error "Error 500
Only the first byte will be assigned to the string offset".

Answer (score 0):

Please check your php version. It seems like you are using latest php version 8 which does not supports some code. Please install php7.0 and try again hope this will help

Comment: Please provide screenshot with error message screen and your php version. So that we can help you

Comment: I have embedded link to image in the question please check.